# CSS hover one div, change 2 specific nested divs

Tags: html, hover

The following is not working.

Only the last hover rule is being applied. Why?

```css
#projects-images-section {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    width: 100%;
}

#projects-images-section .box {
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#projects-images-section .box:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}

#projects-images-section .box:hover .image {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

#projects-images-section .box .overlay {
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: #FFF;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    width: 100%;
}

#projects-images-section .box .image {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="projects-images-section">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="overlay">
            <i class="fas fa-search icon"></i>
        </div>
        <img class="image" src="img/1.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I hover one div and change two specific nested divs in CSS?

Can I do it in CSS only or will I have to use Javascript?

Comment: The image is scaling as well, both hover declarations are working correctly. What are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what the problem was!

The div with the `overlay` class must come last inside the div with the class `box`.

It was also missing a `top: 0` on the `overlay` class.